# Format table to repeat header row in ms word html

Tags: html, ms-word

I'm looking for the mso style code that tells a table to repeat the header row across pages.

My web app creates an html page with a basic table.  Using cfcontent and cfheader, when the page is opened in MS Word.

After I open the file, I can modify the table properties so that the header row is repeated.  I can save the file as html, re-open it and the header row will repeat.  Examining the html, I don't see any difference between a table those header row is repeating and a table that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the difference is expressed by putting the repeating rows inside a

```
<thead>
```

element - I.e. Not using a style name at all.